# Error while running bjam in Boost Python

Tags: c++, boost, build, boost-python, bjam

I have installed boostpro (boost 1.47) in my system. (Windows 7 32-bit)
when I run bjam command on "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_47\libs\python\example" I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_47\libs\python\example\boost-build.jam attempted
to load the build system by invoking

   'boost-build ../../../tools/build/v2 ;'

but we were unable to find "bootstrap.jam" in the specified directory
or in BOOST_BUILD_PATH (searching C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_47\libs\python\
example\../../../tools/build/v2).
```

What does this mean? I don't even have tools/build/v2 in my system. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting with bjam, you could test [Scons](http://www.scons.org/). One day I was writing an application which was using boost::python and Scons helped me a lot. For me everything was much more simpler.

And here is an example of Sconstruct:

```
import os, shutil, platform, re
import SCons.Builder

def copyLibBuilder( target, source, env):
   '''copy library'''
   shutil.copy( str(source[0]), str(target[0]) )
   return

env = Environment()

env.Append( ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH'] })

if(platform.system() == "Linux"):

   env.Append( CPPPATH = ['/usr/include/python2.7'] )
   env.Append( LIBPATH = ['/usr/lib/python2.7'] )

   env.Append( CPPFLAGS = '-Wall -pedantic -pthread -O3 -std=c++0x -lboostpython' )
   env.Append( LINKFLAGS = '-Wall -pthread' )

   env.Append( LIBS = [ 'boost_python' ] )

elif(platform.system() == "Windows"):
   env.Append( CPPPATH = [ Dir('C:/Boost/include/boost-1_52'), # path to installed boost headers 
                           Dir('C:/Python27/include') ] ) # path to installed python headers
   env.Append( LIBPATH = [ Dir('C:/Boost/lib'), # path to boost library
                           Dir('C:/Python27/libs') ] ) #path to python

   env.Append( CPPFLAGS = ' /EHsc /MD /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /W4' )
   env.Append( LINKFLAGS = ' /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS ' )

else:
   print platform.system() + " not supported"

#build C++ library
cpplib = env.SharedLibrary( target = 'sources', 
                source = ['file1.cpp', 'file2.cpp'])
if(platform.system() == "Linux"):
   target = 'my_new_module.so'
elif(platform.system() == "Windows"):
   target = 'my_new_module.pyd'
env.Command(target, cpplib, copyLibBuilder )
```